# Нет перевода для "Очереди проверок"

Tags: дефект, локализация

Нет перевода на странице справки "Очереди проверок" : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-queues.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также отсутствует перевод непосредственно на страницах с описанием как использувать различные очереди.